# Setting GroupName for RadioButton Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I am Adding  Controls dynamically,I want to set the GroupName for radio buttton.

Each row has 3 radio buttons

When I Click a button dynamically rows get added and I have set **GroupName** has OS

So if I add ten Record also I am able to select only one in the added list

I want to generate **GroupName** for each row.

here tk extension is telerik

```
<tk:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">          
            <tk:RadGridView.Columns>
                <tk:GridViewDataColumn Header="1" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Ask}" >
                    <tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton GroupName="os" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </tk:GridViewDataColumn>
                <tk:GridViewDataColumn Header="2" DataMemberBinding="{Binding welcome}}">
                    <tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton GroupName="os"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </tk:GridViewDataColumn>
                <tk:GridViewDataColumn Header="3" DataMemberBinding="{Binding there}">
                    <tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton GroupName="os"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </tk:GridViewDataColumn>
            </tk:RadGridView.Columns>
        </tk:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to bind a groupname with some unique property in your collection, like this: `GroupName="{Binding Id}"`